# ErrorFunction with Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Its seem that typescript have its own windows implementation.

How exactly i can set windows.onerror ?

The only "documentation" I found is

```
onerror: ErrorFunction; 
interface ErrorFunction {
   (eventOrMessage: any, source: string, fileno: number): any; 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The objective of the definition you are showing is to provide the developer with intellisense + typesafety. You would use it like you normally would want to in javascript:

```
window.onerror= function(eventOrMessage: any, source: string, fileno: number){
    // place your body here 
};
```

See it on [typescript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=window.onerror=%20function%28eventOrMessage%3a%20any,%20source%3a%20string,%20fileno%3a%20number%29%7B%0A%09//%20place%20your%20body%20here%20%0A%7D;).

***More:***

If you try to assign it a wrong function you will get an error:

```
// Error: wrong type for fileno
window.onerror= function(eventOrMessage: any, source: string, fileno: string){

};
```

You could omit any of the arguments since functions with lesser arguments are type compatible e.g. the following is valid typescript:

```
window.onerror= function(callitWhaever_ButItWillTakeTheEventOrErrorMessage){
    // place your body here 
};
```

Comment: +1 - I agree with using auto completion to discover the signatures. Bear in mind that this isn't TypeScripts "own implementation" - you are still calling the browser implementation so the normal documentation for window.onerror applies.

Comment: bassarat, buddy! Your playground link no longer works in TS 0.9.5 and I can't figure out how to fix it. :(